# Password can only contain number letters and underscores

Tags: python, passwords

The assignment is:

Write a Python program which prompts the user to create a user account and checks whether the provided user name and password are legal.

Note: A password should start with a letter and only consists of letters, numbers and the underscore symbol "_". The length should be between 8 to 16.

I'm having trouble with the "a password should start with a letter and only consists of letters, numbers and the underscore symbol "_". " part. (I know it's not the most elegant code)

```py
username=input("Please enter a username:")
usepass=input("Please enter a password:")
#username
if len(username)<6 or len(username)>12:
    print("Username is incorrect length. Your username must be between 6 and 12 characters.")
if username.isalnum() == False:
        print("Username must only contain letters and numbers.")
username1=username[0]
if username1.isnumeric()== True :
    print ("Your username must start with a letter")
#password
if len(usepass)<8 or len(usepass)>16:
    print("Password is incorrect length. Your password must be between 8 and 16 characters.")
usepass1=usepass[0]
if usepass1.isalpha()==False:
    print("Your password must start with a letter")
if usepass.isalnum()==False:
    print("Your password must only contain numbers, letters and underscores.")
```

Comment: `"_" not in usepass` means there is no underscore in userpass.

Comment: What problems are you having? What is the expected result and what are you getting? Thanks :)

Comment: @AleSanchez I want the code to return the statement if it contains a special character other than the underscore

Comment: @ash Then you can apply the `isalnum` function to the password, previosly removed the `_` character. Something like `isalnum(passwd.replace('_', ''))`. If that returns false, means that there are other special character.

Comment: Is the password *required* to contain an underscore?

Comment: @BilltheLizard No

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the `isalnum` method, lets try to solve this on your own. The main thing you're lacking here is a loop. For example, if I want to test every letter, I can loop over the letters, and use the `ord` method to verify that every letter is in the right range.

You should structure your methods to test each of the unique conditions as stated in the question. If it passes all the conditions you can return true at the end.

```
def is_valid_user(username):

    # a user name should start with a letter
    is_first_lower = ord('a') <= ord(username[0]) <= ord('z')
    is_first_upper = ord('A') <= ord(username[0]) <= ord('Z')
    if not (is_first_lower or is_first_upper):
        return False

    # only consists of letters and numbers
    for character in username:
        is_lower = ord('a') <= ord(character) <= ord('z')
        is_upper = ord('A') <= ord(character) <= ord('Z')
        is_number = ord('0') <= ord(character) <= ord('9')

        if not (is_lower or is_upper or is_number):
            return False

    # check the other cases like "The length should be between 6 and 12"
    ...

    # All the tests passed so return true
    return True
```

Now you can think about how you can make an `is_valid_password` method. This method should be similar, but have a few different conditions. ***Bonus***: Think about how you can make other methods to share checks between the `is_valid_user` and `is_valid_password` methods.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by creating a new variable that removes an underscore and uses .isalnum to compare that variable

```
rmveudrsre = usepass.replace("_", "")
if rmveudrsre.isalnum()==False:
    print("Your password must only contain numbers, letters and underscores.")
```